# Restore purchases on samsung store

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I'm struggling to restore purchases on samsung store. The purchase flow works great.

```
SamsungIapHelper iapHelper = SamsungIapHelper.getInstance( this, IAP_MODE );    
iapHelper.startPayment(ITEM_GROUP_ID,
                       type,
                       true,
                       mOnPaymentListener);
```

Looking inside the SamsungIapHelper i don't see any relevant methods i can call to do that.
Did someone managed to restore purchases or it will require a server to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Oki, i finally managed to resolve this with the iapHelper.getItemInboxList() method